Is accidentally hitting the opponent's foot (while he is kicking the ball) a foul in soccer?
During yesterday's Euro Cup match between the Netherlands and England, I noticed a situation where a Dutch player accidentally hit the foot of an English player who was attempting to kick the ball. This incident got me thinking about the rules surrounding accidental contact in soccer. Now even though I am Dutch, I just want to understand the rules better and how this gets decided.
The example is here, at around 1 minute: 

. You can see how Dumfries tries to kick but hits the foot of Kane. I think it's very hard to evaluate if this was careless or reckless. In my eyes it doesn't seem intentional or with excessive force.
According to the Laws of the Game, particularly Law 12, fouls and misconduct are categorized based on the nature of the action, whether it's careless, reckless, or involves excessive force. However, I am unclear on how accidental contact is judged, especially when an opponent is actively kicking the ball.
Here are my specific questions:

Is accidental contact, like hitting an opponent's foot while they are kicking the ball, always considered a foul?

How do referees determine whether such contact is careless, reckless, or involves excessive force?

What are the typical consequences (e.g., free kicks, yellow cards) for this type of accidental contact?


I would appreciate any insights or explanations, especially if there are specific examples or references to similar incidents in recent high-profile matches like the one between the Netherlands and England.

The official rule leaves room to interpretation, and referees have guidelines (protect the players) and VAR:

A tackle or challenge that endangers the safety of an opponent or uses excessive force or brutality must be sanctioned as serious foul play.
Any player who lunges at an opponent in challenging for the ball from the
front, from the side or from behind using one or both legs, with excessive force
or endangers the safety of an opponent is guilty of serious foul play.  Serious foul play

That being said, on that particular action you ask about, the Dutch player is stretching his leg up front, facing his opponent, with the studs up. This is a really dangerous action, because the player kicking the ball will hit a pole with the top of his foot.  It's very dangerous, the player can be injured, and that's why referees will blow the whistle and consider it a serious foul.

A studs up tackle is made when a player lunges into a tackle with a leg or both legs outstretched exposing the soles of their boots. Referees are encouraged to at the very least caution (yellow card) players who commit such challenges. studs up tackle and unfair foul tackle


Almost all tackles where the tackler's legs make contact with the opponent before the ball are considered illegal, and heavy contact after initially touching the ball may also be penalised. tackle in football


What does "accidental" mean?
A "fair tackle" is when the tackler makes clear contact with the ball. One is always allowed to play the ball. However beware that if you mis-time the tackle, fail to make contact with the ball and upend the opposing player in the process, it is a foul - even though you did not deliberately intend it that way.
In my view Dumfries clearly fouled Kane. He entirely missed the ball, and brought down Kane in the process.
Some have argued that the fact that Kane had already despatched the ball indicates that Dumfries' action made no difference. But if at the point a player is about to kick a football he catches sight of a large defender coming straight at him, it will inevitably affect the way he kicks the ball.
Dumfries did not play the ball - in the popular jargon "he played the man". That is a foul.

Thank you for your response. I am not mad at the foul (although sad that we lost, England played pretty well so that is not my problem). My problem is that I want to understand better how referees detemrine if something is a foul or not. Can you be way more clear and use the rules to show your logic? The problem with talking about fouls that people tend to be very vague but at the same time black and white. Could you cite the rules?

The Laws of the Game are very general "A direct free kick is awarded if a player commits any of the following offences against an opponent in a manner considered by the referee to be careless [...] tackles or challenges" - any tackle can be an foul if the referee thinks it was careless.

I have done my best to cite the rules as I understand them from a lifetime of being a spectator and watcher of programmes like the BBC "Match of the Day" where refereeing decisions are analysed in details by pundits. But if you believe that Wednesday's referee was in any way unfair to the Netherlands, I would also urge you to take another look at the goal which Saka scored in the second half. Offside??????

@WS2 Nobody other than you has in any way implied the referee was unfair. Please don't bring that into the discussion.

@PhilipKendall You should read the Dutch newspapers.
